# How to take whole width of the screen when binding dynamic values in Universal windows Application

Tags: xaml, gridview, uwp, win-universal-app, itemspanel

I try to populate radio buttons dynamically in Universal windows application. I already wrote `VisualState` for different 
of screens. Now I try to populate the radio button, which are they have to take the whole width of the window. I able to set fixed width for every VisualState But I think that may not good practice and difficult to handle further.   [image: In the large tab radio buttons populate like this]

```
 <GridView Grid.Row="1" Height="auto" Width="auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding DamageLocationList}">
                            <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" />
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </GridView.ItemsPanel>
                            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:DamageLocations">
                                <Grid>
                                     <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource ButtonRadioButtonStyle}"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  Content="{Binding DamageLocation}"   Margin="0" Click="RadioButton_Checked"  />
                                </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
                        </GridView>
```

Comment: can you try with uniformgrid once ??

Comment: uniformgrid not exist in the UWP. Thks

Comment: ok ,,thanks for sharing information.

Comment: Is the number of the items in your GridView fixed? Will it always has six items?

Comment: No it may vary. I use Enum for this. I got the length like this var headerCount = Enum.GetNames(typeof(DamageLocation)).Length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Ashok Rathod said, you can try using `UniformGrid` as the `ItemsPanel` of your `Grid` to make your radio buttons take the whole width of your app's window.

Although `UniformGrid` is not exist in UWP. But we can implement it by ourselves or use a third party `UniformGrid` like what in [WinRTXamlToolkit](https://github.com/xyzzer/WinRTXamlToolkit/blob/master/WinRTXamlToolkit/Controls/UniformGrid/UniformGrid.cs).

Using WinRTXamlToolkit for example, we can using

```
<toolkit:UniformGrid Rows="1" />
```

instead of

```
<VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" />
```

Here `toolkit` is the namespace of `WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls`:

```
xmlns:toolkit="using:WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls"
```

As I didn't set `Columns` property, it will be the default value which is `0`. A value of zero (0) for the Columns property specifies that the column count is computed based on the number of rows and the number of visible child elements that are in the Grid. Since I set `Rows` to `1`, all the items will be put in one row and have the same width.

After this, you may also need to set `ItemContainerStyle` to make the radio buttons stretch like:

```
<GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>
</GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
```